# Can I conjugate 〜もの into れんしゅうする to make れんしゅうもの？ Trying to make "basketball practice", does "バスケットボールのれんしゅうもの" work?

Tags: conjugations

Can I conjugate 〜もの into れんしゅうする to make れんしゅうもの？ Trying to make "basketball practice", does "バスケットボールのれんしゅうもの" work?

And for future reference, can 〜もの be conjugated into any verb to make a noun?

Comment: Do you mean appending/suffixing by 'conjugate'?

Comment: Yes, suffixing! My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, no.

For the particular case, れんしゅう is already a noun 'practice' and バスケットボールのれんしゅう means 'basketball practice'.

---

For most suru-verbs, the preceding word works as a noun. So you can simply drop する. E.g., 学習{がくしゅう}する→学習 (learn/study), 勤務{きんむ}する→勤務 (work).